# Screen monitoring Service in AppWidgetProvider: high memory usage

Tags: android, android-service, android-appwidget

Based on [this](https://github.com/AChep/JellyBeanClock/blob/master/src/com/achep/widget/jellyclock/WidgetProvider.java), I have implemented a `Service` started in `AppWidgetProvider` that watches for screen on/off and screen orientation changes, and updates the widget accordingly. It all works just fine.  The screen events are being detected, and the widgets are reacting as intended.

BUT...

What I'm finding is that the memory usage associated with the app is very high.  On my device, in `Application Manager > Running` my app is noted as having "1 process and 1 service", and the Service is correctly listed in Services, and the app listed under in Processes.

But the memory associated with my app is very high.  For my device, it's 37MB.  But for at least one user, it's approaching 300MB!

When not using this `Service` as above, there doesn't appear to be any issue with high memory usage, at least not that I can tell from the Application Manager.

Is there anything in the way I've implemented the long-running `Service` that would lead to astronomically-high memory usage?  Should there be a separation between the `AppWidgetProvider` and the `Service`, so that any memory usage associated with regular widget updates (e.g. populating `RemoteViews` with bitmaps) does not persist?

Thing is, even when you stop the `Service` in Application Manager, and then start it straight away (without loads of widget updates), the memory usage goes straight back up to what it was before.

I'm a bit lost as to how to proceed... am a bit of a noob with memory management in Android...

Comment: // do stuff with widgets
Post the commneted code

Comment: I've added the basics of what I do on orientation change.  It's semi-pseudo code because there's a lot of stuff that goes into determining the `remoteViews`, based on the new orientation and based on fetching content to go in the widget

Comment: actually you are creating lot of object.so I wanted to know what all u wrote in commented...without that i cant help

Comment: @drmbrewer is createing remoteview involves bitmap?

Comment: yes indeed.  Basically I create the remoteviews with the basic setup (including click handlers etc but NO bitmap yet), then fetch a bitmap from cache to load in via a `partiallyUpdateAppWidget()` using a new remoteviews, then fetch a fresh bitmap and load that into the original remoteviews and use that to do a full `updateAppWidget()`.  Do you think the bitmaps are not being garbage collected?  Thing is, I don't think memory usage grows over time (like for a memory leak)... it just starts big and stays big... some bigger than others.  One user says his memory is only 10MB for my app.

Answer (score 1):

It appears like you are doing heavy operation on bitmap.Bitmaps takes up a lot of memory.You need to recycle i.e `recycle()` the old bitmap before re-initializing or creating new instance of  the bitmap.

```
if(bitmap!=null){
//do ur operation on bitmap
 ..............
 .....................
bitmap.recycle();
}
```

Please go through detail doc on memory management for bitmap.[***Displaying Bitmaps Efficiently***](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html)